# Cannot deserialize exponential numericals with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I am parsing some values from a stock exchanges market and my parser works fine except for some cases where the numerical value from the API I connect to returns something like this:

```
{
   "stock_name": "SOGDR50",
   "price": "6.1e-7"
}
```

In most request the `price` comes in as a decimal (eg: 0.00757238) and everything works fine but when the `price` is an exponential representation my parser breaks.

I am using `Json.Net`: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

My code is:

```
T response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResult);
```

I played with the `JsonSerializerSettings` but didn't come up with any solution. I could parse the problematic numericals by hand but I need the responses to get deserialized automatically to the proper object, depending on the API method called.

Any ideas on how I could resolve this?

Edit 1:

```
public class StockResponse
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public StockResponse(string stock_name, string price)
    {
        Stock_Name = stock_name;
        Price = Decimal.Parse(price.ToString(), NumberStyles.Float);
    }

    public String ShortName { get; set; }
    public String LongName { get; set; }
    public String Stock_Name{ get; set; }
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Decimal Spread { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.NET` includes the attribute of `[JsonConstructor]` that you can attach to a custom constructor. With that, you can do this:

```
[JsonConstructor]
//The names of the parameters need to match those in jsonResult
public StockQuote(string stock_name, string price)
{
    this.stock_name = stock_name;
    //You need to explicitly tell the system it is a floating-point number
    this.price = Decimal.Parse(price, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
}
```

Edit:

In addition to the above, mark your class with the `[JsonObject]` attribute. That is needed for serialization and deserialization. I was able to successfully serialize and deserialize using the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var quote = new StockQuote("test", "6.1e-7");
        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quote);
        Console.WriteLine(data);

        StockQuote quoteTwo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StockQuote>(data);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

[JsonObject]
public class StockQuote
{
    //If you want to serialize the class into a Json, you will need the
    //JsonProperty attributes set
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public StockQuote(string name, string price)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = Decimal.Parse(price, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added a custom constructor following your example, also added an empty constructor, added break-points but for the problematic values it never reaches these contructors, it throws an exception right away from that line `T response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResult);`. For normal values it goes through the custom constructor. Any ideas?

Comment: What does the class that you are deserializing to look like? Can you edit your question to include that class?

Comment: OK I think I got it, I failed to copy your example, I should pass `price` as `string`, now it gets into the constructor but uses a dot instead of a comma to seperate decimal points so it throws an exception because it cannot parse it, that's the only issue right now.

Comment: To fix that, you can either figure out what the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` of the passed number is (sounds like it would be german?) and pass that object into the `Decimal.Parse()` or you can brute force it with a `String.Replace()` method (i do not recommend this, but it is an option)

Comment: Adding ` CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` inside the `Parse` command did the trick. Thank you very much for your so valuable help.